# c# quiz application running score

Tags: c#, button, if-statement

I am developing a quiz application that keeps a running score. For example: an incorrect answer gives -1, and a correct answer gives +1. It works fine, but
I am having trouble with the final question.  I would like my "next" button to change to a "results" button on the form, and then on click, display a message box displaying a message containing the score and a message.

How could I implement this button change only when the answer has been submitted on the last question (as I am catching an exception at the minute)?

Here is my code:

```
    int score = 0;
    int i = -1;
    int a = 0;

    string[] questions = new string[] 
    {
        "Question 1?", 
        "Question 2", 
        "Question 3",
        "Question 4", 
    };

    string[] answers = new string[] 
    {
        "incorrect","correct","incorrect","incorrect",
        "correct","incorrect","incorrect","incorrect",
        "incorrect","incorrect","incorrect","correct",
       "incorrect","incorrect","correct","incorrect"
    };

    string[] quizAnswers = new string[] { "correct", "correct", "correct", "correct" }; 

    public FrmQuestion2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Tutorial3 t3 = new Tutorial3();
        t3.Show(); 
    }

    private void FrmQuestion2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void Sbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (i < questions.Length)
                i++;
            txtQuestion.Text = questions[i];

            RadA.Text = answers[a];
            a++;
            RadB.Text = answers[a];
            a++;
            RadC.Text = answers[a];
            a++;
            RadD.Text = answers[a];
            a++;
            Sbutton.Visible = true;
            Sbutton.Enabled = true;
            Sbutton.Text = "Submit"; 
           // Subutton.Visible = true;
           // Subutton.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Only 4 questions available: Your Score is: " + score + " You need at least a score of 3 to progress");
        }
        if (score >= 3)
        {
            nxtbutton.Visible = true;
            nxtbutton.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if (score < 3)
        {
            nxtbutton.Visible = false;
            nxtbutton.Enabled = false;
            RetryButton.Visible = true;
            RetryButton.Enabled = true; 
        }
    }

    private void Subutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (getSelected().Equals(quizAnswers[i]))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Correct");
                score++;

                txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString("Score:" + score);
                Subutton.Enabled = false; 
                Subutton.Visible = false;
                Sbutton.Visible = true;
                Sbutton.Enabled = true;
                Sbutton.Text = "Next";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect");
                score--;

                txtScore.Text = Convert.ToString("Score:" + score);
                Subutton.Enabled = false;
                Subutton.Visible = false;
                Sbutton.Visible = true;
                Sbutton.Enabled = true;
                Sbutton.Text = "Next";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please start the quiz"); 

        }
    }

    string getSelected()
    {
        if (RadA.Checked)
            return RadA.Text.ToString();
        if (RadB.Checked)
            return RadB.Text.ToString();
        if (RadC.Checked)
            return RadC.Text.ToString();
        if (RadD.Checked)
            return RadD.Text.ToString();
        return "";
    }

    private void RetryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FrmQuestion2 q2 = new FrmQuestion2();
        q2.Show(); 
    }
```

Comment: First: you do not throw any exception, that you can handle. Second: don´t use exceptions for controlling your program-flow.

Comment: @HimBromBeere say if the user clicks next again without the exception it would throw an error: Index was out bounds of the array. I am trying to avoid using this exception by having the button change from 'next' to a new button 'results'

Comment: I assume this happens because you increment `i` by one and afterwards access the i-th element which now might be out of the bounds of your `questions`-array. Simply move that first two lines to the end of your try-block.

Comment: So SButton_Click displays the question and Subutton_Click checks the answer from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

A few assumptions with this answer...

I'm guessing your nextButton's click event is the Sbutton_Click() and there's a submitButton whose click event is the Subutton_Click().

I don't think your Sbutton_Click() event shouldn't do any score checking, it should just display the next question if there is one to display.  Your Subutton_Click() can check the selected answer and then decide to display the nextButton or the resultsButton because your program should know if the last question has been answered.

Then when the results button is clicked, you can check your score and display it, and decide if the retry button is displayed/enabled